# How do I access this.$vuetify using Composition API in Vue 2?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to read and change the value of `this.$vuetify.dark` using composition API in Vue 2 + Vuetify 2. Now that `this.myGlobalOption` is no longer accessible in composition API, how do I do this? I'm gonna need to do this both from within the template and from outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a helper function(composable?) like this:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export const useVuetify = () => {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance();
  return vm.proxy?.$vuetify || undefined;
};
```

Then in your component you can get access to `vuetify` instance via:

```js
  const vuetify = useVuetify();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the modern approach with Vue 3 and [Veutify useTheme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/use-theme/):

```js
<template>
  <template v-if="theme.dark">This is a dark theme</template>
  <template v-if="!theme.dark">This is a light theme</template>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useTheme } from "vuetify";

defineComponent({
  name: "DisplayThemeMode"
});

const { current: theme } = useTheme();
</script>
```

I actually came here because I was looking for the alternative to:

```js
const isMobile = this.$vuetify.display.smAndDown;
```

The good fellows at Veutify have already got you covered with [Display and Platform](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform):

```js
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify';

const { smAndDown: isMobile } = useDisplay();

// or even, more simply using their definition of mobile:
const { mobile } = useDisplay();
```